# Determining if an image is more or less similar to a goal image

Tags: algorithm, image

I'm trying to think of a fast algorithm for the following issue.

Given a goal image G, and two images A and B, determine which of A or B is more similar to G. Note that images A, B, and G are all the same dimension.

By more similar, I mean it looks more like image G overall.

Any ideas for algorithms? I am doing this in Objective-C, and have the capability to scan each and every single pixel in images A, B, and G.

I implemented the following: scan each and every pixel, determine the absolute error in each of red, green, and blue values for A to G and for B to G. The one with the less error is more similar. It works okay, but it is extremely extremely slow.

Comment: images A, B, G are of the same dimensions ?

Comment: "looks more like", as in "to the human eye"? I would suggest the Structural Similarity Index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do better than `X*Y` where X, Y are the image dimensions. Since you need to scan each pixel of the input anyways.

However, one technique you can try is scan random pixels in the image and find the difference. Once you see an image considerably similar or dissimilar than A or B, you can stop.

```
# X, Y are the dimensions
sim_A = 0
sim_B = 0
while( abs(sim_A - sim_B) > MAX_DISSIMILARITY):
    rand_x = random(X)
    rand_y = random(Y)
    sim_A += dissimilar(img_G, img_A, rand_X, rand_Y)
    sim_B += dissimilar(img_G, img_B, rand_X, rand_Y)
```

Comment: I implemented this, and decided to just check some random spots. but how would you define "dissimilar"?

Comment: I mentioned `dissimlar()` to denote the absolute error of RBG values of the two images being compared, as you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using SIFT Algorithm (Scale Invariant Feature Transform). As you just mentioned that you want to find which image is MORE similar to the goal image, then I guess this is the best algorithm. It basically extracts the Invariant features of the image (features that dont change with change in luminous intensity, scale, perspective etc) and then creates a feature vector of these. Then you may use this Feature vector to compare it with other images. you may check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) and [this](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf) for further reference.
Ideally there are computer vision libraries that make things way simpler (i guess it might be difficult to read and write to images in objective C, without any computer vision library). [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/) (opensource computer vision Library) is best suited for stuff like these. It has many inbuilt functions to handle common stuff with images/videos.
Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), which is an image processing library. I don't think it has Objective-C support, but I think it is a better starting place than writing your own algorithm. Usually better not to reinvent the wheel unless you are doing it for personal practice.

Answer (score 0):

The best way, I found out, is to do the following.

First, invert all pixels on the image to make the opposite of the image. This is the most dissimilar image.

Then, to compare image to the target image, compute how far away it is from the most dissimilar image. If it's more far, it's a better image.